# Is it possible to modify an existing style object while using axlsx in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, axlsx

I am using axlsx gem to generate Excel sheets.

I have multiple styles in my Excel. One example is shown below

```
style1 = wb.styles.add_style(:font_name => "Arial", :sz => 10, :i => true, :fg_color => "A6A6A6")
```

Now, I need to write a function which will take this style (and a currency value) as a parameter. This function should just modify the `fg_color` (font color) to red if the currency value is negative (all the other stylings like background color, font size, italics etc should remain the same) and return the modified style.

Is it possible to achieve the same?

```
def get_currency_style(style, currency_value)
  if currency_value < 0
    new_style = <modify ONLY the font color to red in 'style' object>
  else
    new_style = style
  end

  return new_style
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Let your style become a hash, and modify it.

```
def get_currency_style(style, currency_value)
  if currency_value < 0
    style[:fb_color] = 'red'
  end

  return style
end

style1 = wb.styles.add_style(get_currency_style({ font_name: "Arial", sz: 10, i: true, fg_color: "A6A6A6" }, -10))
```

Comment: I get this error. Would you know why?

`undefined method []=' for 36:Integer
Did you mean?  []
Extracted source (around line #30):
              
  new_style = style
  if(forecast_amount < 0)
    new_style[:fg_color] = "FF0000"
  end

  return new_style`

Comment: @Biju your initial style is a hash `styles = { font_name: "Arial", sz: 10, i: true, fg_color: "A6A6A6" }`; then when you call `get_currency_style`, you have to pass the hash and the value: `get_currency_style(styles, -1)`; the `style[:fb_color]` changes the hash's value at index `fb_color`